# @returns throwing error when running locally on docker

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to return array of asset from transaction. So as per the syntax I have added `@returns` and `@commit(false) in cto file` but its throwing error as

```
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
ParseException: Expected ")", "-", "false", "true", comment, end of 
line, number, string or whitespace but "P" found. File 
models/org.zcon.healthcare.cto line 370 column 10
Command failed
```

And when i'm removing the @returns annotation its not throwing any error.
And well its not throwing any error when i'm removing parameter "Patient[]" from @returns annotation.. But it's against the syntax right?
I'm running the application locally using docker swarm.

My docker composer version is v0.19.12

What's wrong? Is this any bug?

In case if you want to see the transaction definition in cto file.

```
@commit(false)
@returns(Patient[]) 
transaction SearchPatient{
  o String firstName optional
  o String lastName optional
}
```

And in logic file

```
/**
 * Sample transaction
 * @param {org.zcon.healthcare.SearchPatient} tx
 * @returns{org.zcon.healthcare.Patient[]}
 * @transaction
 */
async function SearchPatient(tx){
    let queryString = `SELECT org.zcon.healthcare.Patient WHERE (`;
    let conditions = [];
    if (tx.hasOwnProperty('firstName')) {
        var firstName =tx.firstName;
        conditions.push(`(firstName == "${firstName}")`)
    };
    if (tx.hasOwnProperty('lastName')) {
        var lastName = tx.lastName;
        conditions.push(`(lastName == "${lastName}")`)
    };
    queryString += conditions.join(' AND ') + ')';
    let finalQuery =  buildQuery(queryString);
    const searchPatient = await query(finalQuery);
    if(searchPatient.length ==0){
        throw "No Patient Records found!!"
    }else
      return searchPatient;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this error with `composer network install` (deploying to a running Fabric)  I did the network install just fine (see screenshot) with your model and code. I suggest that your error may lie elsewhere in your business network ? Can you add the complete sequence of what you got to get the error? How did you build your bna file?

I also tried your code (ending....):

```
const searchPatient = await query(finalQuery);
    console.log("results are " + searchPatient);
    console.log("element 1 of array is " + searchPatient[0]);
    if(searchPatient.length ==0){
        throw "No Patient Records found!!"
    } else
     return searchPatient;   
}
```

and can see the returned results fine (as shown in console.log - just using a different network name obviously FYI)

[image]

Comment: In composer bluemix its running perfectly. The above code which I posted. But when Im running it locally I need to remove the parameter from @returns annotation in cto file that is 'Patien[]'. It was giving error for the parameter.  Im getting the error when i'm building the bna file itself.  Im building bna file using cli  'composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/healthcare-network.bna'.

Comment: Let me correct my comment. Im gettng the error while im installing the network. The BNA file is getting generated with no issue.

Comment: could you confirm the version of the CLI by doing composer -v just to check you are using the latest version